# How do i read and write with correct encoding?

Tags: powershell, encoding, select-string

This script deletes lines that contain certain strings, in text files.
It has issues handling nordic letters though. According to firefox encoding is

> western european

.

```
$filter  = '.\*.alm'
$pattern = "ASE|MBE|MB1|Network interfaces|Handle|default collector|Proficy|Recovered|AlmODBC|Close Digital Point|DataBlock|Channel|Record|TESTBOOL|OK|OPC|Item|_COMMCHECK_|SYSTEM|ADMINISTRATOR|Unknown|ItemID|Field's|Connection|hutdown|acknowledged|Alarming|Suspended|primary|SAC|reloaded|Fix32|1601-01-01"

(Select-String -Path $filter -Pattern $pattern -NotMatch) |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {Remove-Item $filter} -Process {$_.line | Out-File -Append -Encoding unicode $_.filename }
```

Outfile contains encoding errors such as

> L�G NIV�

I have tried using `Select-String -encoding unicode`, but that just produces gibberish in the outfile

> 㨶㜵㤬㠹嬠啌华ㅃ†⁝彄䅔〲弳呇弱噄䅟⁌††††††䭏††††††††传⁋†

Any idea how to encode correctly?

Input sample:

```
2018-06-13  06:24:59,999 [LUNSC2  ] Fix32.LUNSC2.LUNOP10_COMMCHECK_DV2.F_CV set to 0 by LUNOP10::SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR               
2018-06-13  06:26:01,445 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA204_GT1_DV_AL             CFN              LARM      D_TA204_GT1_Reglerfel                  
2018-06-13  06:26:09,557 [LUNSC2  ] TRE-12-22-I085                OK                 OK      K-FP60 2 MISSADE SPJÄLLMOTIONERINGAR
```

Comment: what's the encoding of the text file ? UTF-8 ?

Comment: Western european is Windows-1252. You should try this encoding: `$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)`. *Edit: Just tried it and it didn't work. Leaving the comment, though.*

Comment: @PalleDue, your suggestion worked when I ran it in Powershell Core v6. Thanks!

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'UTF-8').GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'unicode').GetBytes( '㨶㜵㤬㠹嬠啌华ㅃ†⁝彄䅔〲弳呇弱噄䅟⁌††††††䭏††††††††传⁋†'))` returns `6:57,998 [LUNSC1  ] D_TA203_GT1_DV_AL             OK                 OK`…